# How do I change the default destination page when a customer logs in?

Tags: login

I'd like to create a link which allows a customer to log in before returning to the page they started on, not to the My Account page.

The link needs to work from any location in the site.

`Mage_Customer_AccountController` has a `_loginPostRedirect()` which does the redirecting based on a series of session variables (defaulting to the My Account page). Is there a clean, safe way for me to use one of these session variables (from every page) to make my link work as I'd like? Or is my only option to implement a rewrite for this method and change the call to `$session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customer')->getAccountUrl())`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Admin Panel go to `System > Configuration > Customer Configuration`

In this page, under the `Login Options` change `Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in` from **Yes** to **No**.

When this option is set to No, then the user goes to the login page, it's action will take the `HTTP_REFERER` of the page and save it in the session so the `_loginPostRedirect` function redirects to it.

Answer (score 6):

You can create an observer for this event `controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_loginPost`
with a method similar to this:

```
public function redirectCustomer($observer){
    $url = 'YOUR URL HERE';
    // $url can be : Mage::getUrl('some/path'); or Mage::getUrl('', array('_direct'=>'some-cms-page.html'));
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Can I put this code into the login.phtml file? Will that work?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you disable Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging, in the Admin Panel in System > Configuration > Customer Configuration, in many cases referer is not defined / kept when coming from outside the store to a login protected page.

Only the login link on the page passes referer properly base64 encoded by Magento (check the login URL).
Also, HTTP_REFERER can't be used as it gets lost on the login redirect (anyway it would need further processing to make it encoded).
In _loginPostRedirect() function from Magento core AccountController.php you can find how it works:

```
$referer = $this->getRequest()->getParam(Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::REFERER_QUERY_PARAM_NAME);
                if ($referer) {
                    // Rebuild referer URL to handle the case when SID was changed
                    $referer = Mage::getModel('core/url')
                        ->getRebuiltUrl(Mage::helper('core')->urlDecode($referer));
```

You can see that referer should be passed as a parameter and then it gets decoded by urlDecode().

One solution would be to modify the template file header.phtml and retain the original URL in a session variable, then overwrite the _loginPostRedirect() function to setBeforeAuthUrl() to it.
You can find a working solution which I've tested here: http://www.mihaimatei.com/redirect-previous-page-login-magento/